# Kestrel on ASP.NET Core - high memory usage with netcore1.1 compared to targeting net 4.6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

This may be more server related, however it is the code-base which is using the memory so here seem appropriate.

It's a reasonably self-contained web app with one core project. There's quite a lot of data held in memory so I fully expect it to use more memory than a lightweight app always throwing queries at a database.

When using

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
```

The basic Task Manager memory usage sits around 2GB when under load, and often "feels slow" to the end users.

Recently, partially because of Reshaper throwing false errors, I changed it to

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

ran `dotnet restore` and have redeployed.

Now, under load it's maxing out around 400MB and generally "feels" faster to the end users.

Before getting too hung up on this, is this kind of difference expected? From what I've read, targeting `netcoreapp1.1` means the process is ran with webserver bundled in, however can Kestrel use the additional 1600MB?

Running on a Windows server, is there any advantage to targeting `netcoreapp1.1` over `net46`? If so, I'll setup some performance monitoring and get some numbers behind the users "feelings"!

---

Some additional reading: https://www.ageofascent.com/2016/02/18/asp-net-core-exeeds-1-15-million-requests-12-6-gbps/ - my anecdotal experience suggests that this isn't the case / on windows servers it's best to target the standard framework and run Kestrel on that?

Comment: Kestrel is used in either way. The advantage of running `netcoreapp1.1` is portability. When your app runs with `netcoreapp1.1`, it's most likely ready to go to be used on linux some day (if the native dependencies are available for linux in case you nugets which have native dependencies, like sqlite which wraps around a native library). With targeting .NET 4.6 you can (w/o noticing) add .NET Framework dependencies. Then your app cant be ported easily w/o significant code changes

Comment: That's what I do not understand - as Kestrel is used in both situations, how it is so different... For example, is this article: https://www.ageofascent.com/2016/02/18/asp-net-core-exeeds-1-15-million-requests-12-6-gbps/ running targeting `net46`?

Comment: Well, what's your definition of "under load"? Do you have same amount of requests in both scenarios? Did you use something like wrk (as ASP.NET Core team did for their [internal benchmarks](https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks)?)

Comment: There's absolutely no code changes between the two as the first point. "Under load" is the standard day of the team using the app - about 20 users all logged on and running their activity. So, not load like a huge web-farm out on the internet, just a standard day ticking along. Both readings have been consistent over a number of days (my app pool recycles each night)

Comment: Far too many variables here. Do some quantifiable and measurable load tests, I'm not convinced you'll see much of a difference.

Comment: "feels" faster means nothing and may even be a big red herring, I recommend you test and get actual numbers or you may be chasing your tail.

Comment: @Mardoxx and @DavidG - I fully appreciate that "feel" isn't really anything to go by, but before going down that route, it would be useful to understand, with zero code changes, why one consumes 2GB of memory and the other 400MB... That's a huge difference without doing anything other than swapping frameworks. If there's a real advantage to targeting `netcoreapp1.1` then I'll do the load tests and get some numbers, if not there more pressing tasks to get on with :)

Comment: You use Kestrel as front web interface or you use an IIS with proxy to your Kestrel ? One Possible difference between .netcore and .netframework is the Implementation of the Garbage Collector. Could you check your settings on these ? Like the Use Server Garbage Collection option  based on this link [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) if you go to the `Ephemeral generations and segments` section you will see that the collection will not be forced up to until the memory usage hits 2gb. But that is just a thought

Comment: It's behind IIS with the default proxy to Kestrel. I'll check it those settings as it would seem to correlate... Thanks for the steer